# Blank page issue for Laravel project in Subdomain

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, cpanel

I am having a **Blank Page** issue for **Laravel Project** in a Sub-domain (**cPanel**). The root domain (https://ratul.info/) already has a Laravel application. So I was trying to upload another Laravel project in a Sub-domain (https://ecommerce.ratul.info/). Unfortunately, it was showing a White Screen with no error.

Sub-domain details

- Subdomains: ecommerce.ratul.info
- Document Root: /public_html/ecommerce

Files of `public` and `index.php` is in `/public_html/ecommerce` and other files are in `/public_html/ecommerce/flipmart`.

> The folder structure is Public_html > ecommerce > flipmart

I have changed the path in index.php

```
require __DIR__.'/flipmart/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/flipmart/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Sub-domain is working fine. I have checked with simple HTML files.

Comment: the root should in the public folder in Laravel.

Comment: @JustJeremy I have brought the content of the public folder to the sub-domain root.

Comment: that's your problem right there.  It's not built to have index in the root. It has tons of stuff to do when it first boots.  In cpanal just point your subdomain to the public folder. It will work.

Comment: I was deploying the project from my git repo. Then I was uploading the vendor and .env file. It was creating the issue. When I upload the file as zip everything seems fine. Thanks to @Nahid Hasan Limon

Comment: Something on my gitignore was creating the issue. I don't know what and why. However, the issue is mitigated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

require **DIR**.'/flipmart/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once **DIR**.'/flipmart/bootstrap/app.php';
is all good if Here ecommerce is your subdomain root directory and flipmart is a subfolder of ecommerce (if i am not wrong) .
Also check vendor folder exist.